# Set ssh config from environment variable

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables

I have an ever changing IP address that I like to write into an env variable `$MY_IP` and use it in my SSH config. But this doesn't work:

```
Host my_server
  ForwardAgent yes
  User root
  Port 22
  HostName $MY_IP
```

I also read, that something like `${MY_IP}` could work, but alas, no luck so far.

Only option I see is writing a special shell-script that does the work. Or does anybody have another idea?

Comment: Can you get the server to use DHCP so its IP address is available via DNS? Or in some other way have a DNS server manage the host name -> address mapping? A server- or network-level solution would be more robust than changing things on the client side.

Comment: I may be off here since I never attempted, but the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html) reads: *The keywords CertificateFile, ControlPath, IdentityAgent,
     IdentityFile, KnownHostsCommand, and UserKnownHostsFile support
     environment variables.*

Comment: @JNevill good hint, but alas I don't see `HostName` in that list

Comment: @JohnKugelman these are EC2 instances, and I obtain the IP addresses via AWS SDK. I could use an Elastic IP, but you have to pay for them when the machines aren't running. But I like your idea with the network solution!

Comment: @23tux Yeah. Sorry. That was my point, that `HostName` doesn't natively handle env variables in this config :(

Comment: Try using ProxyCommand. `ProxyCommand ssh "$(echo ${MY_IP})"`?